# Does throwing OutOfMemoryError trigger the heap dump, or does memory actually need to be exhausted?

Tags: java

Does throwing OutOfMemoryError trigger the heap dump, or does memory actually need to be exhausted?

In other words, will a heap dump be produced if I:

```
throw new java.lang.OutOfMemoryError();
```

and have set

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Is this universally true for all JVMs, or is this likely to be vendor-specific?

Why: I want to simulate OOME for testing purposes, and would prefer to have a one-line way of doing this. Just throwing the Error seems logical.

Comment: I don't see what your question has to do with your problem

Comment: It quits the JVM with OutOfMemoryError, but does it write the dump file if it's artificially invoked like this? I'm trying to test the heap dump, which sometimes doesn't get written to disk under actual OOME circumstances.

Comment: Why do you want to test JVM? Do you want to understand your application's benchmarks (memory usage etc)?

Comment: Ah, so the question is if the heap dump get written when you simply invoke `throw new java.lang.OutOfMemoryError();`. So why don't you just try it?

Comment: My heap dumps aren't getting written to disk when OOME occurs, so I need to trigger it on demand to find out why.

Comment: The documentation for the option itself shows allocating a giant object as its example, so it is likely that just throwing is not enough. How about allocating a giant object?

Comment: Just trying it wouldn't seem to be enough, because I know that I have something wrong that isn't outputting the file. Hence asking this question :-)

Comment: Note that `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` only writes a heap dump on the first OOM

Comment: I couldn't find any conclusive documentation on this, whether it's triggered by the Error or by GC failure, or other mechanism.

Comment: First OOM is enough to debug :-)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mosheeshel/0da62975c31e328721341439b3ee902a <- ConsumeHeap example

Comment: [This article](https://dzone.com/articles/memory-analysis-how-to-obtain-java-heat-dump) suggests that it should work to just throw the OOME

Comment: Confirmed (at least for Oracle JRE8) that just throwing the OOME sadly doesn't trigger the dump. Thanks all for the help and the code samples. Of course, this doesn't mean it's the same in the other JREs but it does mean the only reliable way is to fill the heap.

Comment: Of course, I'm now tempted to code-golf this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the documentation doesn't say so and it may or may not be vendor specific, I would just create a large object to force an OOME.

I used this simple Runnable to spawn a Thread causing an OOME when I needed to:

```
private static class OOMRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static final int ALLOCATE_STEP_SIZE = 1_000_000;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long bytesUsed = 0L;
        List<long[]> eatingMemory = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {
            eatingMemory.add(new long[ALLOCATE_STEP_SIZE]);
            bytesUsed += Long.BYTES * ALLOCATE_STEP_SIZE;

            System.out.printf("%d MB allocated%n", bytesUsed / 1_000_000);
        }
    }
}
```